# Identity related scope requests, but no openid scope

Tags: identityserver4

I have a scenario where I absolutely need to get OIDC request without openid scope. Can anybody help please, without openid scope always getting error "Identity related scope requests, but no openid scope".

Comment: Why don't you want to use the openid scope? that is the one that gives you the user identifier (sub claim)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.